# Determining constants $a$ and $n$ for which the vector field is the gradient of some scalar field.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hi I'm looking for help in this problem:

> A fluid flows in the $xy$-plane, each particle moving directly away from the origin. If a particle is at a distance $r$ from the origin its speed is $ar^n$, where $a$ and $n$ are constants. Determine those values of $a$ and $n$ for which the velocity vector field is the gradient of some scalar field.

So my attempt for the solution was making $r=x\hat i+y\hat j$ also $r=||\hat r||=(x^2+y^2)^\frac{1}{2}$, then I procceded to making use of the necesseary condition that $D_1f_2=D_2f_1$, this means $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(a(x^2+y^2)^\frac{n}{2})=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(a(x^2+y^2)^\frac{n}{2})$. But now I'm stuck here, becuase $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(a(x^2+y^2)^\frac{n}{2})=nay(x^2+y^2)^\frac{n-2}{2}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(a(x^2+y^2)^\frac{n}{2})=nax(x^2+y^2)^\frac{n-2}{2}$, clearly both partial derivates are different if $a\not=0$ or $n\not=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your expressions for the components of the velocity are incorrect.  If a particle is moving directly away from the origin with speed $\ ar^n\ $, then the $\ x$-component, $\ f_1\ $, and $\ y$-component, $\ f_2\ $, of its velocity are given by
$$
f_1=axr^{n-1}=ax\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\\
f_2=ayr^{n-1}=ay\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\ ,
$$
so your condition $\ D_1f_2=D_2f_1\ $ holds for any values of $\ n\ $ and $\ a\ $.  However, for particles not at the origin to be moving away from it, you must have $\ a>\ 0\ $.